# Using exceptions for some objects in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code for my tables:

```css
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: #f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

i want to be able to make some rows not use this code on hover.

How can i make an exception for certain rows in my tables?

Comment: Are those random exceptions? What are they based on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give them something to identify them with (e.g. a `class` attribute), then use the [negation pseudo-class selector (**`:not()`**)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) to filter them out:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr class="notThisOne"></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

```css
.table-hover>tbody>tr:not(.notThisOne):hover {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is possible using the `:not()` selector:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

You can for example assign class `noHover` to the elements you want to skip and exclude the class from your css:

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover:not(.noHover) {
    background-color: #f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create a css for the row you don't want to affect
like

```
<table>
<tr><td class="test">1</td><td>a</td><tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>b</td><tr>
<tr><td class="test">3</td><td>c</td><tr>
</table>
```

and add your css

```
.test{
background: blue;
}
```

This is basic but you can then make your own test